# Writing Math Equation in Cordova Apache Phonegap

Tags: cordova

Please Help me!!!, I have problem to write math equation in phonegap with cordova apache platform, I have used mathml in html 5 but it didn't work in phonegap.. Any one in here who can solve this problem?
This my problem.
I write thid code in html

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
      <mrow>
        <msup><mi>a</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <msup><mi>b</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <msup><mi>c</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
      </mrow>
    </math>
```

in moziila display is a^2+b^2=c^2
but in phonegap  and in my handphone the display is a2+b2=c2

Comment: Provide your code sample? What you trying already?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap most likely uses WebKit as underlying browser engine which does not support MathML natively, unlike Firefox. You might need to use MathJax, which is a JavaScript library, or another solution to display MathML formulas in the browser.

It is a good idea to test your application with the Chrome browser because it is also based on WebKit.